# SQL Count from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by

I have a table 'lijsten', a table 'werknemerlijsten' and a table 'categorieen'.

Now i'm using the Query to get the count

```
SELECT id, naam, beschrijving, count(wl.werknemer_id) as aantal
FROM lijsten l
LEFT JOIN werknemerlijsten wl
ON l.id = wl.lijst_id
GROUP BY l.naam
ORDER BY naam
```

But when i try the same query with another count, from another table, the results are false.

```
SELECT l.id, l.naam, beschrijving, count(c.lijst_id) as aantal_cat, count(wl.lijst_id)    as aantal_lijst
FROM lijsten l
LEFT JOIN werknemerlijsten wl ON l.id = wl.lijst_id
LEFT JOIN categorieen c ON l.id = c.lijst_id
GROUP BY l.naam
ORDER BY naam
```

Any idea what i might be doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `left join`s are bringing in tables that have multiple matches for a given id.  The quick and easy way to fix counts is to use `count(distinct)` instead of `count()`:

```
SELECT l.id, l.naam, beschrijving,
       count(distinct c.lijst_id) as aantal_cat, count(distinct wl.lijst_id) as aantal_lijst
FROM lijsten l
LEFT JOIN werknemerlijsten wl ON l.id = wl.lijst_id
LEFT JOIN categorieen c ON l.id = c.lijst_id
GROUP BY l.naam
ORDER BY naam;
```

An alternative approach is to aggregate the tables before the join, doing the counts in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

The following is working! thanks.. Still not quite sure what the distinct is doing.. It is looking for unique values? Thanks!

```
 SELECT l.id, l.naam, beschrijving, count(distinct wl.werknemer_id) as aantal_lijst,     count(distinct c.id) as aantal
    FROM lijsten l
    LEFT JOIN werknemerlijsten wl ON l.id = wl.lijst_id
    LEFT JOIN categorieen c ON c.lijst_id = wl.lijst_id
    GROUP BY l.naam
    ORDER BY naam
```

Comment: distinct will look for not null unique values, and try not using Dutch in your table names if you program. i know its hard when you are dutch. i can understand the table names but not the english poeple on this site..

Comment: Thank you! And i'll remember the not-dutch thing. I was thinking of translating it but do the table names really matter? :)

Comment: you didn't give a structure if the relation is unclear then yes table names do matter and it doenst read nice if you read english and dutch mixed up in a SQL statement..

Comment: Don't forget to accept the *original* answer by GordonLinoff if it was helpful. Doing so encourages others to help you with future questions.