# Having trouble with a nested JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to combine a number of queries, and I'm running into an issue:

```
SELECT OFFERS.ID AS ID, OFFERS.NAME as NAME, PROGRAM_ID, OFFER_TYPE, DATE_CREATED, PROGRAMS.NAME as PROGRAM_NAME, CLICKS_IN, CLICKS_OUT, SALES 
FROM 
    (OFFERS INNER JOIN PROGRAMS ON PROGRAMS.ID = OFFERS.PROGRAM_ID) 
        INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CLICKS_IN FROM CLICKS_IN WHERE OFFER = ID)a 
        INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CLICKS_OUT FROM CLICKS_OUT WHERE OFFER = ID)b
        INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(REVENUE) AS SALES FROM CONVERSIONS WHERE LOCAL_OFFER = ID)c
WHERE OFFER_ACTIVE = 1 AND OFFERS.USER_GROUP = ?
```

I want the OFFER = ID queries to be using the value from OFFERS.ID AS ID but I'm stumped as to how to get it to accomplish that.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to do here. Joining on to count queries? Joins without any conditions?

Comment: Looks more like those `COUNT(*)` should be in your `SELECT` clause like `COUNT(CLICKS_IN.ID)` with joins to `CLICKS_IN`, `CLICKS_OUT`, etc

Comment: CLICKS_IN, CLICKS_OUT, and CONVERSIONS are all separate tables that have the OFFERS.ID as a potential index.  I'm trying to get all the click and sales data linked to all the active offers in the user group.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Count from joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18379262/sql-count-from-joined-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your initial parenthesis are just confusing matters a bit, and the type of selects you are using are more appropriate for subqueries in the SELECTs expression list; try it this way instead:

```
SELECT OFFERS.ID AS ID, OFFERS.NAME as NAME, PROGRAM_ID, OFFER_TYPE
   , DATE_CREATED, PROGRAMS.NAME as PROGRAM_NAME, CLICKS_IN, CLICKS_OUT, SALES 
FROM OFFERS 
   INNER JOIN PROGRAMS ON PROGRAMS.ID = OFFERS.PROGRAM_ID 
   INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT OFFER, COUNT(*) AS CLICKS_IN FROM CLICKS_IN GROUP BY OFFER) AS a 
    ON a.OFFER = OFFERS.ID
   INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT OFFER, COUNT(*) AS CLICKS_OUT FROM CLICKS_OUT GROUP BY OFFER) AS b 
    ON b.OFFER = OFFERS.ID
   INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT LOCAL_OFFER, SUM(REVENUE) AS SALES FROM CONVERSIONS GROUP BY LOCAL_OFFER) AS c
    ON c.LOCAL_OFFER = OFFERS.ID
WHERE OFFER_ACTIVE = 1 AND OFFERS.USER_GROUP = ?
```

This method, as opposed to correlated subqueries *(subqueries that reference outer queries)*, tends to be more efficient unless the tables involved in the subqueries are really huge, and/or you expect very few results in the end. In such cases, your original subqueries can be moved to the SELECT clause almost "as is":

```
SELECT o.ID AS ID, o.NAME as NAME, PROGRAM_ID, OFFER_TYPE, DATE_CREATED, PROGRAMS.NAME as PROGRAM_NAME
   , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLICKS_IN AS t WHERE t.OFFER = o.ID) AS CLICKS_IN
   , (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM CLICKS_OUT AS t WHERE t.OFFER = o.ID) AS CLICKS_OUT
   , (SELECT SUM(REVENUE) FROM CONVERSIONS AS t WHERE t.LOCAL_OFFER = o.ID) AS SALES 
FROM OFFERS AS o INNER JOIN PROGRAMS ON PROGRAMS.ID = o.PROGRAM_ID 
WHERE OFFER_ACTIVE = 1 AND o.USER_GROUP = ?
```

*Sidenote: In queries involving multiple tables it is a good practice to fully qualify any field names used. (For example, I can't be sure where any of these fields come from: PROGRAM_ID, OFFER_TYPE, DATE_CREATED, OFFER_ACTIVE).*

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful

Comment: The first method is what I started with, but it loses cases where there isn't clicks in, clicks out, and sales all present, which is what I was trying to work around.

Second method works for me regardless, because there is a large number of inactive offers that I don't want to gather data on.

Comment: First method should work if you just replace INNER with LEFT; I actually thought of mentioning something when I wrote the answer, but thought it would be excessive.

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I'm still learning how a joins work so you're answer has been very helpful.